# How to create 120 questions with images in Qualtrics (not manually)

Tags: qualtrics

I am trying to create 120 questions that have the same text and options (multiple choice) but with different images below in Qualtrics. Any idea on how to do it without manually creating 120 blocks?

Comment: Do you have API access to Qualtrics?  This seems like a good use case for their Create Question API (https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#create-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Loop & Merge block and pipe in the image url as a loop & merge field.